# Given string, return a dictionary of all the phone numbers in that text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I just started learning dictionaries and regex and I'm having trouble creating a dictionary. In my task, area code is a combination of plus sign and three numbers. The phone number itself is a combination of 7-8 numbers. The phone number might be separated from the area code with a whitespace, but not necessarily.

```
def find_phone_numbers(text: str) -> dict:
    pattern = r'\+\w{3} \w{8}|\+\w{11}|\+\w{3} \w{7}|\+\w{10}|\w{8}|\w{7}'
    match = re.findall(pattern, text)
    str1 = " "
    phone_str = str1.join(match)
    phone_dict = {}
    phones = phone_str.split(" ")
    for phone in phones:
        if phone[0] == "+":
            phone0 = phone
    if phone_str[0:4] not in phone_dict.keys():
        phone_dict[phone_str[0:4]] = [phone_str[5:]]
    return phone_dict
```

The result should be:

`print(find_phone_numbers("+372 56887364  +37256887364  +33359835647  56887364 +11 1234567 +327 1 11111111")) ->`

`{'+372': ['56887364', '56887364'], '+333': ['59835647'], '': ['56887364', '1234567', '11111111']}`

The main problem is that phone numbers with the same area code can be written together or separately. I had an idea to use a for loop to get rid of the "tail" in the form of a phone number and only the area code will remain, but I don't understand how to get rid of the tail here +33359835647. How can this be done and is there a more efficient way?

Comment: maybe get a list of all area codes? Use it to know where phone num isn't over

Comment: https://github.com/kedarmhaswade/cities/blob/master/area-codes.csv

Comment: what does your function return instead?

Comment: https://github.com/OWASP/passfault/blob/master/wordlists/experimental/US%20Area%20Codes.txt - better

Comment: @kbunarjo it returns {'+372': ['56887364 +37256887364 +33359835647 56887364 1234567 11111111']}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (the regex pattern explained here - [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6UEbeT/1)):

```py
import re

s = "+372 56887364  +37256887364  +33359835647  56887364 +11 1234567 +327 1 11111111"
pat = re.compile(r"(\+\d{3})?\s*(\d{7,8})")

out = {}
for pref, number in pat.findall(s):
    out.setdefault(pref, []).append(number)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "+372": ["56887364", "56887364"],
    "+333": ["59835647"],
    "": ["56887364", "1234567", "11111111"],
}
```